# Is there a way that I can get a count of rows with a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have been using this LINQ statement:

```
 var phrases = await db.Phrases
               .AsNoTracking()
               .ToListAsync();
```

But what I need is to get a count of the number of rows in Phrases.

I have never used LINQ to do this before. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: `.Count()` ????

Comment: What @Habib said, and also, one of the golden rules for software development: RTFM

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sync version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468851(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var phrasesCount = db.Phrases.Count();
```

The [async version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.countasync(v=vs.113).aspx) (assuming this is EF):

```
var phrasesCount = await db.Phrases.CountAsync();
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if you're not returning items, (I know that here you seem to want items), that you can get a more performant count from the db by using the .Query() method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186674/entity-framework-poor-count-performance

Comment: @ChadMcGrath it seems from the question and [linked docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#queryCount) that this is only applicable for counting *related* entities, which is not the case here. It seems that [Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcollectionentry.query(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCollectionEntry.Query) is an instance method on `DbCollectionEntry`, so I'm not sure the first bit of code in your answer compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Charles provided valid answer, but since you never worked with LINQ before, it's nice to know, that .Count() allows you to pass predicate as an argument.

For example, if you would like to count phrases that are longer than 30 characters, you could write something like this

```
var longPhrases = db.Phrases.Count(phrase => phrase.Lenght > 30);
```