# Server side paging & sorting and filtering Performance

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datatables

I have only one table in database with 2 million records , i want the user to be able to browse the data and also have the ability to sort data and filter it.
also user should be able to navigate between pages

Here is my MVC controller

```
 public class AssetController : Controller
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public ApplicationDbContext DbContext
        {
            get
            {
                return _dbContext ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _dbContext = value;
            }

        }

        public AssetController()
        {

        }

        public AssetController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        // GET: Asset
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
        {
            IEnumerable<Asset> query = DbContext.Assets;
            var totalCount = query.Count();

            #region Filtering
            // Apply filters for searching
            if (requestModel.Search.Value != string.Empty)
            {
                var value = requestModel.Search.Value.Trim();
                query = query.Where(p => p.Barcode.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.Manufacturer.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.ModelNumber.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.Building.Contains(value)
                                   );
            }

            var filteredCount = query.Count();

            #endregion Filtering

            #region Sorting
            // Sorting
            var sortedColumns = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns();
            var orderByString = String.Empty;

            foreach (var column in sortedColumns)
            {
                orderByString += orderByString != String.Empty ? "," : "";
                orderByString += (column.Data) + (column.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant ? " asc" : " desc");
            }

            query = query.OrderBy(orderByString == string.Empty ? "BarCode asc" : orderByString);

            #endregion Sorting

            // Paging
            query = query.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);


            var data = query.Select(asset => new
            {
                AssetID = asset.AssetID,
                BarCode = asset.Barcode,
                Manufacturer = asset.Manufacturer,
                ModelNumber = asset.ModelNumber,
                Building = asset.Building,
                RoomNo = asset.RoomNo,
                Quantity = asset.Quantity
            }).ToList();

            return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, data, filteredCount, totalCount), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

and below is index.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Properties</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>BarCode</th>
                            <th>Manufacturer</th>
                            <th>Building</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var datatableInstance = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("Get","Asset")"
                },
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'BarCode' },
                    { 'data': 'Manufacturer' },
                    {
                        'data': 'Building',
                        'searchable': true,

                    },
                    {
                        'data': 'Quantity',
                        'searchable': true,
                        'render': function (Quantity) {
                            return "$ " + Quantity;
                        }
                    },
                ],

            });

        });  
    </script>

}
```

I used JQuery data-tables , code is working fine if i have small number of rows - less than 100000 , but if i have large number of rows , it becomes very bad

It takes too long in the following line

```
var filteredCount = query.Count();
```

How can i enhance the performance

Comment: Have you tried `query.query().Count()?` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186674/entity-framework-poor-count-performance

Comment: query() method not found

Comment: You're building a query containing 4 `LIKE '%...&%` clauses that can't use indexes. What kind of performance did you expect?

Comment: i need to make filter - can you help ?

Comment: i have the same performance issue with counts.  i'm paging so only retrieving the top ten rows, but the table is large so the counts are killing performance.  any updates or advice here??

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, instead doing "var totalCount = query.Count();" try to make an sql statement with a count over the table, probably you will get a better perfomance.

var totalCount = _context.SqlQuery("Select count(0) from yourTable").FirstOrDefault();

I haven´t tested the perfomance with Count(), but with Distinc() the difference is remarkable.

Hope it helps